# How to use afterInstall event in installer class?

Tags: c#, installation

I have this under afterinstall event which creates a registry key.

```
private void install_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("*\\Shell\\Test");
    reg.SetValue(String.Empty, "My App");
    RegistryKey command = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("*\\Shell\\Test\\Command");
    command.SetValue(string.Empty, Application.StartupPath + "\\test.exe %L");
    command.Close();
    reg.Close(); 
}
```

How can I use this event properly? How can I create setup that uses this? installshield, innosetup etc. Or can we do with installshield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or can we do with installshield?

You can add registry keys with InstallShield.

[Edit: the following is true for InstallShield Spring 2012. It is possible the details are different for different versions of InstallShield.]

In the Installation Designer tab, under System Configuration, click Registry. On the bottom pane, "Destination computer's Registry view", create the subkeys you wish to be created on installation (so that looks like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Test\Command`).

And then create the values you want: an unnamed string value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Test` with the value `My App`, and an unnamed string value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Test\Command` with the value `"[INSTALLDIR]test.exe" "%1"`.

Alternatively, you can import a .reg file with the values you want set.

Doing this will create a component for your registry entries. If you want it all in one component, create the component first and do this under the "Registry Data" item underneath that component.

Doing it this way is easier than calling into code you write, as if you do it with a custom action (which is how you'd call into your code), you'd also need to create a rollback action, an uninstall action, and an uninstall rollback action.

Comment: Thanks. [INSTALLDIR] did help. I have one more question how can we change its icon on the right menu?

Comment: @gckpis I actually don't know. I'd look at what other programs do. I know `Notepad++` adds itself to right-click menus and has an icon. You can actually open up msi files in InstallShield and look at their components and changes they make.

Comment: I see. well how can I change its sorting on the registry? Because it creates at under the top (explore)